# Mobile background is not working in WordPress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

My mobile background was fine up until yesterday. I'm not sure whats going on. What I've done so far:

Deactivated all plugins I thought could be interfering (had more than 30) Below is my current bare minimum active

**Screenshot of Plugins**

[image]

My fiddle with my custom CSS and HTML source :

```
[JSfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jd31z0ve/)
```

I am also getting this warning whenever I try to save or update anything when the page refreshes

[image]

Comment: What changed?  Anything with the server settings or any files?

Comment: no, nothing that  i know of.

Answer (score 0):

About your css: you have many misplaced curly braces "{}", make you have properly closed all curly braces and have no additional css .just like

```
.site-logo {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.site-header {
background: #000823;}
```

and seems like you have an conflict with child theme and other components.

and this post explain about header modification errors.
[How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Comment: OK - good idea. I went ahead and fixed a few syntax errors. Site still not fixed in mobile. althought i havent tested a different device. does it look wrong to you? like half of the header background missing. www.offtopicpolitics.com

Comment: http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/1040/0427324985.jpg
this is the output in my browser. Please mark in the image, I mean mark the wrongly rendered area.

Comment: Rakib, this issue is only affecting mobile display. Im using an LG G2 and this is what im getting http://imgur.com/G2KtxYE

Comment: sorry for being so late, yes its still affecting the mobile view.

Comment: nice to see that you have fixed it.